# Karate Mocks- `How to create a mocks to get a value from json using the key

Tags: karate

Karate Mocks- `How to create a mocks to get a value from json using the key.
In below example, i want to get the name using the id, iam not able to retrieve

response.json

{

"2727": "siva",
  "2728": "kavi"

}

demo-mock.feature

Feature: stateful mock server

Background:

```
* def company = read('response.json')
```

Scenario: pathMatches('/companies/search/{id}}')

```
* def name = company.id 
* def response = name
```

test.feature

Feature: integration test

Background:

```
* def port = karate.env == 'mock' ? karate.start('demo-mock.feature').port : 8080
* url 'http://localhost:' + port + '/companies/search'
```

@mock
  Scenario: get company name

```
Given path '2727'
When method get
Then status 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#pathparams

```
* def id = pathParams.id
```

Comment: HI Peter, i tried the above method, still iam not able to get the id value. Getting reponse empty.

 Scenario: pathMatches('/companies/search/{id}}')

    * def id = pathParams.id
    * def response = id

Response:

> GET http://localhost:59233/companies/search/2727
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: localhost:59233
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.2)

09:15:03.236 response time in milliseconds: 122.74
1 < 200
1 < Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: @Siva sorry I give up. your question itself was un-clear this comment is worse. follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue